# nowWrap not working in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, nowrap

I am having issues with noWrap. I would like to remove the side containers (left/right).

This is my code:

```js
this.map = L.map('mainMap').setView([0, 0], 1)
L.tileLayer('http://127.0.0.1:8081/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   minZoom: 1,
   maxZoom: 3,
   noWrap: true
}).addTo(this.map)
```

And result is:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect from the `noWrap` option? Have you tried the difference when it is set to `false`? If you can explain what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you reaching that goal.

Comment: Figured it out, sorry. NoWrap works, the background was not set.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Can you edit and post what you did to correct this and set the background? It will help anybody else who comes across this question as well.

Comment: on the parent, div set the background of the images/maps that you are using.